# Juju Integration with OpenStack: "credentials not found"

Tags: juju, openstack

My Requirement is to use Juju as a generic VNF manager with Openstack as a Provider. I have an Openstack provider Network and I have my VNFs with Centos Based images. I have created a VM with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and installed Juju 2.0 2.0-beta17-trusty-amd64.

First I tried Manual Bootstrapping to run my Charm to deploy my VNF. Manual Provisioning to Centos Machine failed.

Now I am trying to bootstrap with OpenStack. My Config files are as below

```
~/.local/share/juju:
clouds.yaml  config.yaml  credential.yaml

clouds:
  systack:
    type: openstack
    regions:
      RegionOne:
        endpoint: http://x.x.x./v2.0
        auth-types: [userpass]
```

My Credentials are also correct

```
credentials:
  systack:
    default-credential: xxxx
    default-region: RegionOne
    juju-dev:
      auth-type: userpass
      password: xxxx
      username: xxxx
      tenant-name: xxxx
      domain-name: default

config.yaml

agent-metadata-url: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/
agent-stream: devel
default-series: centos7
```

When I bootstrap Juju it fails with below logs. Could not figure out whats going wrong.

```
ubuntu@localhost:~/.local/share/juju$ juju bootstrap openstack systack --config config.yaml --debug
00:14:10 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.0-beta17 gc go1.6]
00:14:10 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 no credentials found, checking environment
00:14:10 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 detecting credentials for "systack" cloud provider: openstack credentials not found
00:14:10 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:459 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands/bootstrap.go:407: } {github.com/juju/juju/cmd/modelcmd/credentials.go:122: detecting credentials for "systack" cloud provider} {github.com/juju/juju/provider/openstack/credentials.go:99: openstack credentials not found}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your credentials file should be called credential**s**.yaml -- note the s, which is missing from the filename in your `ls` output.

FYI, there are commands that you can/should use to manage credentials, that don't involve touching the files directly:

- `juju add-credential`, which will prompt you for the credentials, and update credentials.yaml,
- `juju set-default-credential`.

Comment: I've the same issue but I used that command to generate the credential but nothing. I open this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134575/deploying-apps-on-openstack-via-juju